# Salesforce.com: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

In our production org, we have a system of uploading sales data into Salesforce using command line data loader. This data is loaded into a temporary object **Temp**.  We have created a formula field (which combines three fields) to form a unique key. The purpose of the object is to reduce user efforts for creating the key manually.

There is an after insert trigger on **Temp**  which calls an asynchronous method which upserts the data to another object **SalesData** using the key. The insert/update trigger on **SalesData** checks the various fields and creates/updates the records in another object **SalesRecords**.  After the insertion/updation is complete, all the records in temp object **Temp**  are deleted. The **SalesRecords** object does not have any trigger on it and is a child of another object **Sales**. The **Sales** object has some rollup fields which are summing up fields from **SalesRecords** object.

Lately, we are getting the below error for some of the records which are updated. 
    UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

Please provide some pointers to resolve the issue

Comment: Which DML in which trigger is throwing the err?

Comment: The upsert of SalesRecords is throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could either be caused by conflicting DML operations in the various trigger execution or some recursive trigger execution. i would assume that the async executions cause multiple subsequent updates on the same records, probably on the SalesRecords object. I would recommend to try to simplify the process to avoid too many related trigger executions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised you were able to get this to work in the first place. After triggers should be used with caution and only when before triggers can't be. One reason for this is that you don't need to perform additional DML to make changes to records, since in before triggers you simply change the values and the insert/update commit happens automatically. But recursive trigger firings is the main problem with after triggers.

One quick way to avoid trigger re-entry is to use a public static Boolean in a class that states whether you're already in this trigger from the same thread of execution.

Something like:

```
public static Boolean isExecuting = false;
```

Once set to `true`, any trigger code that is a re-fire can be avoided with:

```
if(Class.isExecuting == false)
{
   Class.isExecuting = true;

   // Perform trigger logic
   // ...
}
```

Additionally, since the order of trigger execution cannot be determined up front, you might be seeing an issue with deletions or other data changes that depend on other parts of your flow to finish first.

Also, without knowing the details of your custom unique 3-part key, I'd wonder if there's a problem there too such as whether it's truly unique or not. Case insensitivity is a common mistake and it's the reason there are 15 AND 18 character Ids in Salesforce. For example, when people export to Excel (a case-insensitive environment) and do VLOOKUPs, they would occasionally find the wrong record. The 3-digit calculated suffix was added to disambiguate for case-insensitive environments.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for this same error lead me to this post:

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Unable-to-obtain-exclusive-access-to-this-record/td-p/345319

Which points out some common causes for this to happen:

1. Sharing Rules are being calculated.
2. A picklist value has been replaced and replacement is in progress.
3. A custom index creation/removal is in progress.
4. Most unlikely one -  someone else is already editing the same record that you are trying to access at the same time.

Posting here in case somebody else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error multiple times today.  Turned out one of our vendors was updating their installed package during that time in the same org.   All kinds of things were going wrong also - some object validation exceptions were being thrown on DMLs, without any error message content.

Answer (score -1):

Resolution
The error is shown when a field update such as a roll-up summary field is being attempted on a parent object that already had a field update to cause the roll-up summary field to calculate.  This could also occur if a trigger or another apex job running on the master object and it also attempting to do an update.

You can either reduce the batch size and try again or create separate smaller files to be imported if this issue occurs.

Comment: At least site your sources: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000130351&language=en_US